# have+to go or have to go

Tags: semantics

> I have to go now. I have to leave now. I have to study Englsih.

Can I stop after "have" for a moment?

I have (a few seconds later like 2~3 and continue to say) to go now.

Or Do I have to say the whole thing "have to": I have (a few seconds later like 2~3 and continue to say the whole thing "have to") + have to go now.

In other words, 1. I have+(2~3sec pause)+to go now. 2. I have+(2~3sec pause)+have to go now.

Comment: _Have to_ is a phrasal verb, equivalent to _must_, so it would be odd to pause before the _to_.

Comment: Indeed; the have and to are so closely linked that some dialects even run them into each other to make the word "hafta". https://www.lexico.com/definition/hafta